# Total number of labels inside a module of TFS repository

Tags: c#, powershell, tfs, label

I need to find out how many labels are there inside each module of a collection in Team Foundation repository.
I am using TFS 2013.
I know we can get it from Visual Studio. But we need a script which gets us the number of labels as output.
Can anyone help me out in getting a C# or a Powershell code to obtain the same?

TIA

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .NET Client Libraries to get this: [.NET client libraries for Visual Studio Team Services (and TFS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet)

Code sample:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace GetLabels
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string tfscollection = "http://xxx:8080/tfs/defaultcollection";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfscollection));
            VersionControlServer vcs = ttpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            string labelname = null;
            string labelscope = "$/";
            string owner = null;
            bool includeitem = false;
            int labelnumber;
            VersionControlLabel[] labels = vcs.QueryLabels(labelname,labelscope,owner,includeitem);
            labelnumber = labels.Length;
            Console.WriteLine(labelnumber);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In a similar way, is there any code to get Current size of each module inside a collection?